# Reset the bootstrap-select using jQuery iniside a form

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

For example i have `option` with `selectpicker` implemented.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myFormskpd" >
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="id_objek_penugasan_skpd" name="id_objek_penugasan_skpd" data-live-search="true"  title="Pilih data objek penugasan" >
<option data-subtext="01" value="1" >SKPD Provinsi Maluku </option>
<option data-subtext="02" value="2" > SKPD Kabupaten/Kota Maluku </option>
<option data-subtext="03" value="3" >Satuan Kerja Pusat </option>
<option data-subtext="04" value="4" >Proyek Pusat  </option>
<option data-subtext="05" value="5" >Proyek Daerah  </option>
<option data-subtext="06" value="6" >BUMN  </option>
<option data-subtext="07" value="7" >BUMD  </option>
</select>
</form>
```

When i have selected the option, i couldnt make the option set to blank again ( set to null )

I used `reset` to make the my `myFormskpd` clear.

`$('#myFormskpd')[0].reset();`

But it didn't work for me. I have tried:

```
$('#id_objek_penugasan_skpd').selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

It's only deselect one select picker. Are there a way to reset the form so it make all the `selectpicker` clear ? for example, i have a form. Inside this form, i have five different `selectpicker`. Usually, i used `$('#myFormskpd')[0].reset();` to clear the form in  one go. But it didn't work in `selectpicker` it still show the previous selected option.

Comment: Is this the correct plugin? https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: `$('#myFormskpd').selectpicker('deselectAll');`

Comment: @MasterYoda yeah, that one

Comment: @tonoslfx didnt work, and `myformskpd` is a form id not, select id

Comment: `$('#id_objek_penugasan_skpd').selectpicker('deselectAll');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

https://codepen.io/zerolfc/full/pWYwNq/

```
$(function() {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    $('button').click(function() {

        $('#id_objek_penugasan_skpd').selectpicker('deselectAll');

        // or $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');

    });


});
```

Comment: so i just add all the select option which i want to clear the selected option inside ` $('button').click(function() {` ?

Comment: can we specific the select picker inside a form ?

Comment: i mean all inside form `myformskpd` that have `selectpicker` class will be set to null again, how ?

Comment: how to specified div inside form ?